# phantomjs command line never works

Tags: command-line, syntax, phantomjs, command-prompt

I'm trying to run a command line in the phantomjs prompt (to create a PDF screenshot of a website)

So I launched phantomjs.exe and after the **phantomjs>** I typed :

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.google.com test1.pdf
```

Whatever I type, I get a

*Expected an identifier but found 'rasterize' instead*

*phantomjs://repl-input:1 in global code*

(rasterize or any other thing I typed)

Even the help, I cannot call (-h / --help) http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html

Both phantomjs.exe and rasterize.js are on the same folder on my PC.

What am I doing wrong in the syntax ?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to run this script directly on your command line and not inside the phantomjs interpreter:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.google.com test1.pdf
```

Comment: @OP and make sure rasterize is in the current path

Comment: It worked !
The complete steps are :
1 - launch cmd
2 - go to the folder where phantomjs.exe is located (eg : cd C:\temp\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin)
3 - make sure rasterize.js is in that same folder
4 - type my phantom command : phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.google.com test1.pdf